# Google App Engine sort costs for videogame's highscore tables

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm considering creating my own GAE app to track players' highscores in my videogames. I've already created a simple app that allows me to send and recover Top 10 highscores (that is, just 10 scores are stored per game), but now I'm considering costs if things grow.

Say a game has thousands or millions of players (hehe, not mine). I've seen how applications like OpenFeint are able to sort your score and tell your exact rank in a highscore table with thousands of entries. You may be #19623, for example.

In order to keep things simple, I would create Top 100 score tables. But what if I truly wanted to store all scores and keep things sorted? Does it make sense to simply sort scores as they are queried from the database? I don't think so...

How are such applications implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GAE it's easy to return sorted queries as long as you index your fields.  If your goal is just to find the top 100 scores, you can do an ordered query by score for 100 entities - you will get them in order.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_order

The harder part is assigning the number to the query.  For the top 100, you'd basically go through the returned list of 100 entities, and print a number beside each of them.

If you need to find a user at a particular rank, you can use a cursor to make narrow your search to say whoever is at rank #19623.

What you won't be able to do efficiently with this is figure out the rank of a single entity.  In order to figure out rankings using the built in index, you'd have to query for all entities, and find where that indivdual entity is in the list.

The laziest way to do the ranking would be something like search for the top 100, if the user is in there, show their ranking, if not, then tell them they are > 100.  Another possibility is to occasionaly do large queries to get score ranges, store those, and then give the user a less accurent (you are in the top 500, top 1000 etc), without having the exact place.

Comment: Also, you could possibly write a CRON job to save this info to another table.  That would make the look-up rather quick.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that clarifies how to tackle this. The 'laziest' way is useful, but I had totally forgotten about indexes - I've not used them yet. I'll have a look at them. Thanks once again!

Comment: You can't use cursors to find the user at a particular rank - at least, not without iterating over all the preceding entries first.

Answer (score 1):

Standard database indexing - both on App Engine and elsewhere - doesn't provide an efficient way to find the rank of a row/entity. One option is to go through the database at regular intervals and update the current rank. If you want ranks to be updated immediately, however, a tree-based solution is better. One is provided for App Engine in the [app-engine-ranklist](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/) project.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with TyprX typing races (GWT + App Engine). The way we did it without going through millions of rows it to store high score like this:

```
  class User {

    Integer day, month, year;
    Integer highscoreOfTheDay;
    Integer highscoreOfMonth;
    Integer highscoreOfTheYear;

  }
```

Doing so you can get a sorted list of daily, monthly, yearly high scores with on query. The key is to update the users records with their own best score for each period as they finish their games.

Then we added save the result to memcache and voila.

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about using exception processing. How many of the thousands of results each day/hour will be a top 100 score? Keep a min/max top-100 range entity (memcached of course). Each score that comes is goes one direction if it is within the range, else another direction (task queue?) if not. Why not shunt the 99% of non-relevant work to another process, and only have to deal with 100+1 recs in whatever your final setup might be for changing the rankings.

Comment: Yes, we certainly considered this option too, but thanks for sharing.